# pymongo get keys of all collections

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I need a code that will show me the main keys of all collection names. I want to be able to use this on different mongo instances so I don't want to use the exact name of collections.

```
import pymongo
import sys
import json

    from pymongo import MongoClient
    
    
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017, maxPoolSize=50)
            db = client.list_database_names()
            document = db.collection_name.find_one()
            for k in document:
                print(k)
```

but when I run it, it outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bla.py", line 12, in <module>
    document = db.collection_name.find_one()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'collection_name'
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db` is a list of all your databases names
You have to get a database object for each of your database names.
Then you have to get all the collection of each database.
And you will be able to print the first document of each collection

```
import pymongo
import sys
import json

from pymongo import MongoClient

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017, maxPoolSize=50)
    list_databases = client.list_database_names()

    for database_name in list_databases:
        # Create a Database object
        db = client.get_database(database_name)
        
        # Get list of collections names in that database
        list_collections = db.collection_names()

        for collection_name in list_collections:
            # Create a colection object
            collection = db.get_collection(collection_name)

            # Print the first element of that collection
            print(collection.find_one())
```

Comment: And to print only the keys names, not the content?

Comment: Since the output of `collection.find_one()` is dict, you can simply do `collection.find_one().keys()`